# convert string to image

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, converters

I'm trying to convert my string into a 173x173 png-image. Is that somehow possible and if yes: how? need the url afterwards to use it on my backtile.

the string can contain letters,numbers, and "-./"

found something like that, but don't seem to work at all:

```
 private Uri ToImage()
    {
        string imageString = "";

        byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imageString);
        System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(imageString.ToCharArray(), 0, imageString.ToCharArray().Length - 1,
        imageBytes, 0);

        System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

        ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        bitmapImage.SetSource(ms);
        return bitmapImage.UriSource;
    }
```

Comment: Anybody understand this code as I understand it? :)

Comment: Is this what you want? http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/convert_image_to_base64_string_and_base64_string_to_image.aspx

Comment: I can't tell if he's got an encoded image in a string, or he's trying to write a string to a tile image. Which one is it?

Comment: i try to convert the string to a image and then return the url of the image.

Answer (score 1):

To load image fom a base64 string you can use it:

```
Image img;
byte[] fileBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imageString);
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    ms.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
    img = Image.FromStream(ms);
}
```

You can save this image on the server and send a URL of file to client or send the image "on-the-fly":

```
Response.ContentType = "image/png";
img.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Png);
```

In this case, the image url are the page url, ex.:

```
img src="getBacktile.aspx?id=XXX"
```

Comment: I'm not sure this answers what he's trying to accomplish.  Though, to be honest, I'm not sure what the goal is here.  Anyway, one thing to consider with respect to backtiles, is that PNG is not usually a good choice, because the size can exceed the maximum size for a tile image.  I usually use JPG, because on the phone, any lossy-ness of the format is usually masked by the smaller display size.

Comment: jpg doesn't support transparency, thats the problem.

Comment: This is wrong. Windows Phone does not have the Image.FromStream method.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove/comment line code of **public abstract int GetBytes(char[] chars, int charIndex, int charCount, byte[] bytes, int byteIndex);**

```
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(imageString.ToCharArray(), 0, imageString.ToCharArray().Length - 1,
        imageBytes, 0);
```

It work on me.

And more thing, convert using line code

```
Image img;
byte[] fileBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imageString);
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    ms.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
    img = Image.FromStream(ms);
}
```

don't work. Since in Windows Phone 7 don't provide method **Image.FromStream(ms)**.